# I have some cofusion about whether to use images for text or google font

Tags: html, css, fonts

I am want to use a font that is not popular. this font exist in google fonts and also in Photoshop. I am confused because both ways will have some loading time, I know that images are not the good way to go for texts (but at least the image will be internal), however google font will introduce some overhead as the font will be requested from an external source

which method has good performance (in terms of load speed):

1) using Photoshop to write the text and save it as an image than use the image in my webpage? or

2) using google font?

3) and if using google font. do i have to download the font file with all formats and then put it in my website folder? or I just use the html link tag to? which one is more efficient.

and thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Your first and foremost concern should rather be accessibility. And in terms of that, real text content wins over “text” that is just part of an image every time of course.

Comment: Go with Google Font rather than an image. And you just need to add a js link (provided by google fonts) at the top of your page to be able to use a font.

Comment: If you use CDN, the Google font shouldn't take time to load at all.

Comment: I would upvote CBroe's comment 100 times if I could. ***Never*** use pictures of words in place of words. +Ever+.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google fonts are CDN, so they take up zero of your server resources (while images do). That said, Google fonts can slow down your page. But typically only when you're using a handful of fonts. I wouldn't be concerned at all with 1 or 2. Overall, either method would be little to no concern in the end.

***However***, using images for text is a flash back to 1998. Bad practice. More so on your end, as updating text, changing design, running A/B tests, accessibility, SEO, and maintaining the site in general will become a major pain in the a**. Simplest answer? **Avoid it.**

Directly from Google Fonts site:

> **Tip**: Using many font styles can slow down your webpage, so only select
>   the font styles that you actually need on your webpage.
>
> **Tip**: If you choose only the languages that you need, you'll help
>   prevent slowness on your webpage.

Example usage:

```
// include in the <head/> of your website
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
```

then:

```
// in your css:
h1 { font-family: 'Open Sans', Arial, serif; font-weight: 400; }
```

Done. Very little resources.

Answer (score 1):

**Use google fonts.**

The Google Fonts CDN is built to deliver content, content loaded from it will probably load faster then it would if it was on your server.

You don't have to download the font, or worry about browser support, simply add the `<link>` tag to your HTML.

You should NOT use images to display text, for several reasons:

1. Screen readers can't read text in an image
2. Size. Depending on the size of the image and font, the image may be larger than the font file.
3. A major pain to update
4. UX problems. i.e. Users can't copy text, select, etc.

When should you use images?

When you need a text effect that can't be achieved with CSS, SVG, or canvas(Not that many). As noted by [@Stephen P](https://stackoverflow.com/users/17300/stephen-p) in the comments below, you should still add text, just [visually hide it with CSS](https://css-tricks.com/the-image-replacement-museum/)

Comment: _"When you need a text effect that can't be achieved"_ — in a case like this you should _still_ use text, and [use a replacement technique](https://css-tricks.com/the-image-replacement-museum/). ***Never*** just drop text and use an image instead.

Comment: SVGs would also be considered images I think.

Answer (score 0):

You can download google fonts .ttf file or whaterver format you like or supports and call that file instead of accessing from a url. Which will be much much faster. And yes images are truely bad as it makes impossible for search engine to read.